# getbootstrap.com vs bootstrapdocs.com: are these supposed to be the same things?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've was thinking on migrating the Bootstrap versions on my site and was looking into my old cdn referrals.
Currently, my site is using Bootstrap 3, linking to maxcdn.bootstrap.com courtesy of bootstrapdocs.com

getbootstrap.com seems to have the latest versions. But the legacy CDNs listed on the site does not even contain the CDNs offered on bootstrapdocs.com(getboostrap.com is missing the CDNs for bootstrap-theme.min.css for the version 3s), on top of using stackcdn(as opposed to bootstrapdocs.com's maxcdn)

bootstrap.com also only seems to offer up to version 3.3.6 while there exist a bootstrap 4 and 5 is currently in the alpha stages.

Why are there 2 sites for the same thing?